# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventlistner'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventlistner' when adding this code, i can't get my head around it :(

```
$('video').addEventlistner('timeupdate', function(event) {
    var current = Math.round(event.target.currentTime * 1000);
    var total = Math.round(event.target.duration * 1000);
    $('temps_total').empty().appendText(total);
    $('temps_courant').empty().appendText(current)
    $('temps_restant').empty().appendText(total - current);
    });
```

Comment: Note that the native function is spelled with "listener" (and capitalized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `addEventListener` not `addEventlistner` **but** neither are jQuery methods.

Read this http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('video').on('timeupdate', function(event) {
    var current = Math.round(event.target.currentTime * 1000);
    var total = Math.round(event.target.duration * 1000);
    $('temps_total').empty().appendText(total);
    $('temps_courant').empty().appendText(current)
    $('temps_restant').empty().appendText(total - current);
});
```

Comment: What? addEventListener is right here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: no, melpomeme spotted lower case L, it wasn't just the missing e

Answer (score 4):

Because `$('video')` returns a jquery object.

Here is what you can do:

```
$('video')[0].addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event) {
```

Comment: Just capitalize the `L`... but +1 since I'm certain you'll fix it,.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects do not have an `addEventListener` method.
Instead, you should call `.bind()`.