# jQuery bind: run function before media ends

Tags: video, bind, media, jquery

I'm building a simple php page that plays a playlist of videos back to back using HTML5 video & the jQuery bind function to fadeIn & play the next video once the current video has ended.

Binding the functions to the *ended* event works pretty well, but I'd like to fire the fadeIn & play function (lets say) 20 seconds BEFORE the video is ended.

But I can't seem to figure out how to make this magic happen. Is this even possible?

My HTML:

```
<video controls preload="auto">
<source src="sequence01.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>

<video controls preload="auto">
<source src="sequence01.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('video').bind("ended", function(){
   $(this).fadeOut(20000).next().fadeIn(20000).get(0).play(); 
});
```

---

## **SOLVED!**

```
$('video').on('timeupdate', function(event) {
  var current = Math.round(event.target.currentTime * 1000);
  var total = Math.round(event.target.duration * 1000);

  if ( ( total - current ) < 20000 ) {
    $(this).fadeOut(2000).next().fadeIn(2000).get(0).play();
  } 
});
```

thanks so much for the help guys, I was able to cobble an answer together using your awesome comments, and this other *seemingly irrelevant* SO post:

[Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventlistner'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572527/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-addeventlistner)

if anyone has a cleaner way of putting this together that'd be awesome, but this seems to be working pretty well for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first answer I gave had some issues. I have modified it to be correct

```
var myVid = document.getElementById("video1");

myVid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if( (myVid.duration - myVid.currentTime ) < 20000 ) {
        console.log("less than 20 seconds left"); 
    }
});
```

this requires that you give an id to a video tag and the console.log should be replaced with whatever you want to do inside the function. however I have tested this and it works well.

in your case you will need to run a loop and bind the event to each video but make sure that you reference the actual video and not one of its properties such as length or item.

if you copy and paste this code into the `<script>` tags of the try it yourself section of this example it will work.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_progress

here is a reference of the video object properties and events

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: hmm, looks like it should work but i can't quite get it going. :-\

Comment: I had some bad logic in the if statement but i fixed it. try it now and if it isn't working let me know where it is failing?

Comment: yeah, i'm still just learning jquery, but that logic is definitely correct now. Looks like this is missing a closing ) on the 2nd to last line. i closed that up, but now i get: 
_Uncaught TypeError: Object length has no method 'addEventListener'_

Comment: I modified the answer and tested it. hope this does the trick!

Comment: ahh awesome! I actually just solved this one thanks to yours & @david-houde answers. but i'll try yours out right now, looks like it might be a more elegant solution... thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these:

```
$('video').currentTime;
$('video').duration;
```

I am not going to write the code, but you should check that

```
if ( ( this.duration - this.currentTime ) < 20000 )
```

Check out http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: thanks for the link - i'm trying to figure this out but it seems a bit over my head. i understand the disparate parts, but can't quite figure out how to bring them together.

does the if statement need to be in a function after the $('video').currentTime; ??